# How to use "0" before number in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, vb6

I want to print the result in my program like this: `06:03` in visual basic 6
How can I add **"0"** before numbers ?

```
m=6
h=3 
print m;" : ";h
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

You have to use `Format()`

```
m = 6
h = 3

Debug.Print Format(m, "00"); " : "; Format(h, "00")
```

**Output**: 06 : 03

Comment: You should vote to close as duplicate when there is a clear duplicate, not answer the question again.

Comment: I am sorry I was not aware that there was a duplicate. Is that the reason for Downvote?

Comment: @jbabey  He wanted to answer the question.  I would have done the same thing.  The question has already been marked as a duplicate.  I find your comment not only unnecessary, but more than a little irritating.

Comment: @jbabey - hardly sufficient grounds for a downvote.